# Where is getApiClient on BaseGameActivity?

Tags: android, google-play-services

The Google documentation at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init says that

> Your game must have a reference to the GoogleApiClient object in order
>   to make any API calls to the Play Games services. During its
>   activity's lifecycle, your game can retrieve the GoogleApiClient
>   object at any time after onCreate(), by calling getApiClient(). For
>   example:
>
> Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), LB_ID, 12345);

Initially the page also says:

> The BaseGameActivity class wraps the GoogleApiClient, reducing the complexity of setting up a connection with the Google Play servers and managing user sign-in.

However, I can't find `getApiClient()` in `BaseGameActivity` or in `GameHelper`. Where is it?

Answer (score 4):

The `BaseGameActivity` is a wrapper class around `GamesClient`, which is deprecated as of February 7th, 2014.

You may use either`BaseGameActivity` with `GamesClient` or `GoogleApiClient`.

I think the documentation isn't finished yet. It's from yesterday.

To use the `GoogleApiClient` please see

https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin#signing_the_player_in_at_startup

Answer (score 0):

I can't look at my own code until I get home, but perhaps my memory will be good enough :-). I don't believe I use getApiClient() anywhere. Perhaps BaseGameActivity is doing that part for you. You may need getGamesClient() instead. Again, going from memory, so this might be useless prattle :-).

Answer (score 0):

Today they updated BaseGameActivity to use the new GoogleApiClient. Apparently they updated the docs days before the code.